# What is the launch intent for VLC with special parameter

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open VLC player with some parameter such as **start location** or **width & height** of activity, While googling in website's, view that intent parameter something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setPackage("com.android.vlc");
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(foo);
startActivity(i);
```

Could anyone Help me how i can do that?
Thanks in advance.